# Get Events via REST API gives an error

Tags: rest-api

Any GET of list view gives an same error for me 
`/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Event/listviews/00B28000002cAhLEAU/results`  ?

The error is the same

```
message: What.Name, ActivityDate, toLabel(Status), toLabel(Priority), Owner.Alias ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:60 No such column 'Status' on entity 'Event'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
errorCode: INVALID_FIELD
```

Did I mess up with configuration or it's not supposed to work at all?